# jqtree - JSON data undefined

Tags: jquery, json, view, tree

I am trying to implement http://mbraak.github.com/jqTree/ via json.

This is the function I called in the `<head>`:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    $.getJSON('../controller/das/dus.php',
                        function(data) {
                            $('#tree1').tree({
                                data:data
                        });

                    });
});
```

My php file:

```
<?php session_start();
header('Content-type: application/json');

require_once '../../model/getdata.php';

        $sql = 'SELECT * FROM slode';
        $stmt = getaccessdata::getInstance()->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute();
        $array = $stmt->fetchAll( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC );
        $json = json_encode( $array );

        echo $json ;
?>
```

These are the javascript files that I inserted:

```
<!-- jquery -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style/jquery/jquery-ui-1.8.14.custom.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js"></script>

<!-- jqTree -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jqtree/tree.jquery.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style/jqtree/jqtree.css" />
```

This is the json data:

```
[{"id":"1","stand":"Civ","cat":"cat1","stand":"100","savedate":"2011-03-29 18:53:47","cap":"150"},{"id":"2","stand":"asdasd","cat":"cat2","stand":"120","savedate":"2011-03-29 18:53:47","cap":"150"},{"id":"3","stand":"asdasd","cat":"cat3","stand":"80","savedate":"2011-03-29 18:53:47","cap":"250"},{"id":"4","stand":"asdasd","cat":"cat4","stand":"300","savedate":"2011-03-29 18:53:47","cap":"350"},{"id":"5","stand":"asdasd","cat":"cat5","stand":"450","savedate":"2011-03-29 18:53:47","cap":"450"},{"id":"6","stand":"asdasd","cat":"cat6","stand":"40","savedate":"2011-03-29 18:53:47","cap":"550"}]
```

I really don't know what I'm doing wrong. It always displays "undefined" where the data should be.

I don't know how to implement the tree structure and how it is displayed in the jqtree.
(json parse in jqtree?)

The desired result:
if "stand" is the same in the different json data it should make a new label and the cat should be used as children:

```
-Civ (=label)
--cat1 (=children)


-asdasd (=label)
--cat2 (=children)
--cat3 (=children)
--cat4 (=children)
--cat5 (=children)
--cat6 (=children)
```

How could I convert my json data to this structure:

```
    var data = [
    {
        label: 'node1',
        children: [
            { label: 'child1' },
            { label: 'child2' }
        ]
    },
    {
        label: 'node2',
        children: [
            { label: 'child3' }
        ]
    }
];
```

Answer (score 1):

The format of the JSON should be :

```
    var data = [
    {
        label: 'node1',
        children: [
            { label: 'child1' },
            { label: 'child2' }
        ]
    },
    {
        label: 'node2',
        children: [
            { label: 'child3' }
        ]
    }
];
```

meaning that your array should have label and children in it, u can put other stuff as well but those are MUST

Comment: user asked about it,how to do this!

Comment: Though the dates show otherwise, he edited it. It didn't show this at start, as you can see by other answers.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is, you suppose to return the json in proper format like this

```
    {
    "0": {
        "id": "1",
        "stand": "100",
        "cat": "cat1",
        "savedate": "2011-03-29 18:53:47",
        "cap": "150"
    },
    "1": {
        "id": "2",
        "stand": "120",
        "cat": "cat2",
        "savedate": "2011-03-29 18:53:47",
        "cap": "150"
    },
    "2": {
        "id": "3",
        "stand": "80",
        "cat": "cat3",
        "savedate": "2011-03-29 18:53:47",
        "cap": "250"
    },
    "3": {
        "id": "4",
        "stand": "300",
        "cat": "cat4",
        "savedate": "2011-03-29 18:53:47",
        "cap": "350"
    },
    "4": {
        "id": "5",
        "stand": "450",
        "cat": "cat5",
        "savedate": "2011-03-29 18:53:47",
        "cap": "450"
    },
    "5": {
        "id": "6",
        "stand": "40",
        "cat": "cat6",
        "savedate": "2011-03-29 18:53:47",
        "cap": "550"
    }
}
```

Mean give key:value pair to your json

You can do validate your json file here http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: No, my json seems to be valid. It works if I try this: $.getJSON("../controller/das/dus.php", function(data) {
   $.each(data, function(key, val) {
   alert("JSON Data: " + key + val.silo);
   });
 });

Comment: That means you got the answer of your question.

Comment: no :-( I dont know why the data wont display in jqtree. It alway says undefined... perhaps it is wrong to write data:data in getjson function, but this is how it is described on the developer page. I really freak out with this...now I already spend about 10 hours ...

Comment: the suggested format is like this in document  var data = [
    {
        label: 'node1',
        children: [
            { label: 'child1' },
            { label: 'child2' }
        ]
    },
    {
        label: 'node2',
        children: [
            { label: 'child3' }
        ]
    }
];

Comment: where is your label and children tag

Comment: can you just edit you question and add a image that describe your desire result. so i can understand what needs to be done. also not to forget to use your json in your image.